# sudo command not found after trying to use docker without sudo

Tags: ubuntu, docker, sudo

Hello everyone & happy new year!

I'm currently discovering docker. 
In order to avoid typing `sudo` with each command, I've followed the instructions on the manual page: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

Here are the commands I've used:

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
```

(they said that the "docker" group already exists)

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Not only I still have to write `sudo` with each docker command, but now `sudo` doesn't work anymore with any other command than docker.

Something like `sudo docker images` works, but a simple `sudo ls` will display:

```
sudo: ls: command not found.
```

How can I fix this? What did I wrong?

I work on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which user are you connected as when running these commands?

Comment: 1) It you type "echo $USER" do you get your user as output? 2) Type "cat /etc/group" to check your user belongs to docker group (you dhould find something like "docker:x:999:yourUser" 3) Remind to logoff and logon again before usermod setting becomes active.

Comment: Yep, when I type "echo $USER" I get my user as output. 
My user belongs to docker group, it appears in /etc/group but not when I typed "groups".
To solve that, since I don't know how to log off/log in without restarting my computer, I found this command which works fine: newgrp docker.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

As per docker documentation, after adding the user to the docker group you must logout and later for sample testing you just try to run the hello-world without sudo.

If everything seems to be fine you can see the output from docker. If there is an issue you'll see the problem from the dockerdaemon.

I Hope you did all of these steps specified in docker documentation without making any mistake.

Now coming to your issue it doesn't affect to the sudo at all. I have installed docker in several machines including production. I never faced any issue so far. Make sure you($USER) added to docker group.

I recommend to reinstall if it's not a production.

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/docker-engine.* /tmp/

sudo apt-get remove docker-engine

You can do fresh Installation..

If you face the problem again, please attach the screen shot.

Comment: Concretely, I don't know what I should do to logout and then login. What am I supposed to log off? The docker documentation is unclear about that.
Fortunately I've found a better way than rebooting my computer: `newgrp docker` updates the group so that I don't have to log out/log in.

About `sudo` I don't know what happened. I'm almost sure that `sudo ls` didn't work and now it works again, I couldn't say exactly what I did to solve that...

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Seems it is strange behaviour, but somehow it worked... it is better if you could understand what causes to sudo not works. But after all you got your problem solved.. that's good news anyway..!!